# Animate height to bottom of viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Update with refactor (sorry)
So i'm trying to animate a container that can be anywhere on the screen with a dynamic number of items (overflowed) to either the last item, or if theres more items than viewport space, the bottom of the viewport. (see example).
How can i write an animation to handle both cases simultaneously? Animating max-height alone is too janky because its trying to animate as if its animating to its max-height always.

Fiddle is better example.
https://jsfiddle.net/h9kuzfay/26/

```css
#d {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container {
  margin-top:20px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 250px;
  animation: height-to-vp 0.5s ease forwards;
}

.item {
  height: 16px;
}

@keyframes height-to-vp {
  from {
    max-height: 100px;
  }
  to {
    max-height: 100vh;
  }
}

#d2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}


.container2 {
  margin-top:20px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 250px;
  animation: height-to-vp 0.5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes height-to-vp2 {
  from {
    flex: 0;
  }
  to {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="d">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-content">
    <button>Should animate up to last item</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="d2">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-content">
    <button>
      Should stay in viewport
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex and combine with a max-height animation to only show few items at the start:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-top:20px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 250px;
  max-height:50px;
  overflow:auto;
  animation: height-to-vp 3s ease 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes height-to-vp {
  from {
    flex: 1;
    max-height:50px;
  }
  to {
    flex: 1;
    max-height:100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Hello
  </div>
    <div class="item">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>



<div class="bottom-content">
  <button>Should remain in viewport</button>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry "container" can be positioned anywhere on the page so VH animation won't work, because if container is margin-top: 50px it will go to vh 100 + 50px?

Comment: @ShanonJackson there is no vh animation :) i animate flex from 0 to 1 ... and it will also work with margin ;)

Comment: @ShanonJackson i added margin and padding to the example :)

Comment: Hey @Temani, sorry my bad i missed out a specification.
the number of items in container can contain a dynamic number of items initially but should only show 5  (initially) (overflow hidden).
then when it animates if theres only 10 items it should animate to show 10, but if theres 100 it should animate to bottom of viewport and leave overflow hidden for rest.

is that possible?

Comment: @ShanonJackson in this case keep flex:1 and animate max-height ... from any value to a big value

Comment: any way to do it without max-height? or manipulating max-height? because animating to max height means the animation will always run as if its animating to that height making it look janky
I.e if max height 10000px, and you animate to height + 200px the animation will run as if its animating to 10000px

Comment: @ShanonJackson well there is no magic way :) all depends on your code and your needs .. so edit you question with the exact code using describing what you want exactly then i will give the solution ;)

Comment: @ShanonJackson ok but you don't have to edit with my code, you should keep you initial problem :) if you update with my code you make my actual answer obsolete and people may think i did nothintg ..  so am obliged to remove it

Comment: @ShanonJackson i updated my answer let me know if it works for you